# woocommerce no_rest_route error message for v2 API on new WP WC Site

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Hoping someone might be able to help me solve this one. I have a website im trying to integrate with

https://www.domainname.com/wp-json/wc/v2

Returns {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}

On another site I have on a completely different server I also have

https://www.domainname2.com/wp-json/wc/v2

it returns the info for the API, both are new sites and I cant quite figure out why I cant see v2, but V1 appears

for some reason, https://www.domainname.com/wp-json/wc/v1 works, but I need more access to the API, which only appears to be available in V2 onwards

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same error.
In my case it was API version mismatch. I was trying with  https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers though my actual api url was https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/customers

Check your api url whether the version is 'V1' or 'V2' or 'V3'.